# Having trouble with the mod operator; I'm not getting the result I'm expecting

Tags: java

There is a puzzle on codingbat.com that seemed quite trivial but when I solved it and submitted, it was marked wrong when the argument **45** or **15** was passed in to the method. What am I doing wrong here in my logic to the following question?

> Return true if the given non-negative number is a multiple of 3 or 5,
>   but not both. Use the % "mod" operator -- see Introduction to Mod

My solution:

```
public Boolean old35(int n) {
  if( n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 && !(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) ){
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Codingbat's solution that makes no sense to me at all:

```
public Boolean old35(int n) {
    return n % 3 == 0 ^ n % 5 == 0;
}
```

Comment: `^` is "exclusive or" - it means "one of these conditions but not both".

Comment: You aren't checking the case "NOT BOTH".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&&` operator takes precedence over `||`, so it takes place after `!(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)` but before the or `||`. With `45`, it's true that it's a multiple of `3` and `5`, so the `!` returns `false`.  It's a multiple of `5`, so `true & false` yields `false`.  It's a multiple of `3`, so `true` or `false` yields `true`, which is incorrect according to the requirements.

You can correct your solution by inserting parentheses to force the `||` before the first `&&`:

```
//  v                          v
if( ( n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 ) && !(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) ){
```

Codingbat's solution uses the XOR operator, `^`.  This operator means either one or the other is true, but not both, which fits the requirements exactly.  Also, there is no reason for the `if`; you can return the boolean expression directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is almost right. You just need brackets:

```
if((n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) && !(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) )
```

Without brackets it is treated as

```
if( n % 3 == 0 || (n % 5 == 0 && !(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)) )
```

`^` is exclusive or. `x ^ y` means either `x` or `y` is true, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

return *(n%3 == 0 || n%5 == 0)* && **!(n%3 == 0 && n%5 == 0)**;

You can check both conditions and then pass the results of those conditions through an AND gate (&&).